# Why windows use icons which are in the %sytemRoot%installer folder?

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons

I found my driver `c:` ,have a lot of `.msi` file in `%SystemRoot%Installer` Folder.Then I delete them.

Now A lot of software can't found the icon file,and I choose to changed icon for the shortcut,there is a tip as follow:

[image]

Who can explain that why windows 10 not use the real install folder such as (C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\Icons)?

How to solve the problem,expect reinstall them.

Comment: We can't tell you why they would do that, but if more than  a couple peices of software are affected this way, then I would guess that there is an installer framework which they all use to build installers for their applications, and that this installer framework just doesn't move icon files when it creates shortcuts.  MSIs are made to be cached, so they don't expect you to delete the contents of the intstaller folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one type of shortcuts in windows. In this case you have some that are so called "advertised shortcuts" or "windows installer shortcuts". You will probably notice that you can also not specify the path to the executable with such a shortcut. The idea with those is that the shortcut does not link to the program but to some cached setup. In case an error is detected it should be possible to rerun parts of the installation to remediate the problem. Because of that the icon is also part of the msi in that cache so that if the executable of the program is damaged (which could lead to no icon) in the best case the icon is still displayed correctly. On the program start the damage would be detected and reinstalled. By deleting the installer folder you destroyed this mechanism and you can only fix this with reinstalling all the programs.

It is however dubious if you would have ever really needed this mechanism to begin with as corruption in installed programs is not a common thing. So as circumvention you could delete all the advertised shortcuts and replace them with "normal" ones by hand. Those would point directly to the executables and use their embedded icon or an ico file in the same location. It might be a bit of work to find the correct executable sometimes but the program is completely independant of the repair mechanism so it would work normally.

As a final note: Please do not delete any files in your %SystemRoot% folder, if you are not 101% sure what they do.